# Add a program to startup in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I'm doing development with a [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server all the time, so I need to add it to the startup in Windows.

I did this with my Windows XP machine, it is simple to do in X, but when I switched to Windows 7 I couldn't find an option to run programs at startup.

How do I make a program run at startup in Windows 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest way would be to put it in your Startup Folder.

They have moved it in Windows 7; now it can be found here:

> %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Start, Run, paste the above, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This will open the startup folder in Explorer.

Now drag and drop a shortcut to the app to whatever you wish to run into the startup folder.

[image: Windows 7 Programs Startup folder]

Comment: You can get to the same location by just typing `shell:startup` from the Start search input or Start->Run input. There are [loads of other useful shortcuts to these special folders](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get to the **Startup** folder using the **GUI** you can access it from **Start,All Programs,Startup**. Right click on this folder and you can open either the Startup folder for your profile or the **all users** folder (which required Admin permissions to update).

Now drag and drop a shortcut to the app as stated in the earlier answer.

[image]